# Serializable exception in spring mvc application

Tags: spring, tomcat, serialization, datasource

I am developing webapplication using Spring MVC and Tomcat.
Sometimes I am getting java.io.NotSerializableException exception.

Caused by:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException:
 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

Here is my datasource in spring config.xml

```
 <bean id="dataSource"  
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2:DB212cc" />  
    <property name="username" value="#XYZ" />  
    <property name="password" value="1234" />  
</bean>
```

Can any one suggest me where and how to serialize this datasource.

> I am using spring-jdbc-4.0.0.M2.jar

Comment: You're getting this exception when doing what? What's the complete stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to avoid the above exception I added listener tag in web.xml and its working fine.
That means,listener that exposes the request to the current thread through RequestContextListener.So, we have to register listener tag in web.xml.
listeners are useful for third party-servlets..

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```